# ADFS 2.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, single-sign-on, adfs

Wanted to know if ADFS 2.0 can be installed on Windows Server 2012? The below link says it can be installed and gives command to install but that command fails throwing the error 'ad-federation-services' is a invalid role.

http://blog.msgeneral.nl/2012/11/installing-and-configuring-adfs-on.html#comment-form

I have also tried installing using the command provided in another link which mentions about installing ADFS 2.1. But it installs ADFS 3.0. http://www.flexecom.com/install-adfs-2-1-on-windows-server-2012-for-office-365-part-1/

I am verifying the version of ADFS installed using the below link and I cant find FSConfig.exe file.

"jorgequestforknowledge.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/gathering-architectural-details-from-your-adfs-infrastructure-adfs-version/"

Is ADFS 2.1 installed on Windows Server 2012 and ADFS 3.0 installed on Windows Server 2012 R2 by default?

Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADFS is a role that you can install using the server manager or the powershell cmdlet. No need to use external installer to add this feature to a Windows Server 2012. 
The correct powershel cmdlet is:

```
Add-WindowsFeature ADFS-Federation
```

Afaik you can't downgrade or choose which version to install as it will install the latest version automatically which in this case is 3.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2 and 2.1 on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

The version of AD FS bundled with Windows Server 2012 R2 is 3.0. This cannot be changed.

That said, it is SAML 2.0 compliant, which is really all that should matter.